# Notation of isomorphism of a polynomial base

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let's say that we have a basis in polynomial $R_3[x]$: $$B =\{ x^3 + x^2,x,6\}$$

Is the following notation okay:
$$B=\{x^3+x^2,x,6\}\cong\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\}$$
Or can we write normal equal sign ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well firstly the space of polynomials of degree smaller or equal than 3 is 4-dimensional ($\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ would be a basis for example).

Regarding your question: The two sets are not the same so it is not okay to just write a "normal" equal sign. I think what you want so say is that the spaces spanned by the two sets are isomorphic.
So you could write $\mathrm{span}(\{x^3+x^2,x,6\})\cong\mathrm{span}(\{(1,1,0,0),(0,0,1,0),(0,0,0,1)\})$ where $\mathrm{span}(\{x^3+x^2,x,6\}):=\{a \cdot (x^3+x^2)+b\cdot x+c\cdot6|a,b,c\in R\}$ is the set of all linear combinations.

Does that answer your question?

Comment: So I could also say {Basis as polynomials} $\cong$ {Basis as vectors}

Comment: @BiliDebili The $\cong$-sign in this case should mean that there exists an isomorphism between the two sets but the sets are no vectorspaces so the notation does not work. If you are looking for a more compact notation for the span I also know of the notation $\langle 1,x,x^2,x^3\rangle$.